# Stop printing fully qualified class names with log4net

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have a C# project with log4net. The log4net configuration prints stack trace detail for each line, eg.:

```
<param name="LogPattern" value="[%date] %stacktracedetail{3} %m" />
```

However this makes the lines a little unreadable, as the the stack trace prints the fully qualified class name for each method. Even the parameter names are prefixed with `System`:

```
[2018-03-14 12:14:02,265] a.b.class1.myMethod(System.String param1, System.Int32 param2) > a.b.class2.myMethod(System.String param1, System.Int32 param2) > a.b.class3.myMethod(System.String param1, System.Int32 param2) logmessage
```

How can I remove the fully qualified class names? eg.:

```
[2018-03-14 12:14:02,265] class1.myMethod(String param1, Int32 param2) > class2.myMethod(String param1, Int32 param2) > class3.myMethod(String param1, Int32 param2) logmessage
```

Comment: The Framework itself only works with fully qualified classnames. Using directives allow the compiler to infer the rest of the Classname, if they are unambigious. Personally I feel you should not override this. Or at least only for very specific built-in types (like string and int) and only during display. In the raw log, it is better to have all the information at least once. But to view the log, you might replace "System.String" with "String". A simple Dictionary<String, String>, a loop and String.Replace can do that operation.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this through configuration alone, as far as I'm aware. If you really want this to work though, I would suggest creating your own `Appender` by extending whichever appender you're currently using (e.g. `log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender`) and overriding the `RenderLoggingEvent(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)` method.

In your overriding method, you're going to want to call the base `RenderLoggingEvent(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)` to render the event into a string. Now that you've got your string, you could use regex to strip out anything you don't want to see in the log.

Something like the following (note: this is just headcode, it may not work properly, it's just to illustrate)

```
public class MySpecialFileAppender : log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender
{
    protected void RenderLoggingEvent(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        var rendered = RenderLoggingEvent(loggingEvent);
        var adjusted = AdjustText(rendered);
        writer.Write(adjusted);     
    }

    private string AdjustText(string inputText)
    {
        return "HELLO WORLD!!!";
    }
}
```

This is a quick and dirty solution as to do it properly would require you to [write your own Pattern Layout Converter](https://devstuffs.wordpress.com/2012/01/12/creating-your-own-pattern-layout-converter-for-log4net/) based on the existing `stacktracedetail` converter which refers to the class `log4net.Layout.Pattern.StackTraceDetailPatternConverter` which is internal. So... yeah, that'd be a lot of work.